# Grep qstat output and copy files once done

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, pbs

I am using PBS job scheduler on my cluster. In bash,I would like to monitor the job status and once the job is done I would like to copy the results to a 
certain location(/data/myfolder/)

My qstat output looks like this:

```
    JobID  Username Queue Jobname SessID NDS TSK Memory Time  Status 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    717.XXXXXX  user XXXX       SS  2323283 1  24  122gb --     E
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a script [here](https://github.com/NYU-Molecular-Pathology/protocols/blob/8e5533325be0c9b5692e569cabb5f9913995047d/misc/check_node_hostname.sh) that does this (for SGE). I started to excerpt just the relevant parts for you, but it will probably be easier for you to start with the full script and just insert the `qsub` commands inside the `submit_job` function, and then put the code you want for copying the results after the `wait_job_finish` command in the script. You can remove the log printing at the end if you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script will submit a qsub job and check on host information for the cluster
# node which it ends up running on
# ~~~~~ CUSTOM FUNCTIONS ~~~~~ #
submit_job () {
    local job_name="$1"
    qsub -j y -N "$job_name" -o :${PWD}/ -e :${PWD}/ <<E0F
set -x
hostname
cat /etc/hosts
python -c "import socket; print socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())"
# sleep 5000
E0F
}

wait_job_start () {
    local job_id="$1"
    printf "waiting for job to start"
    while ! qstat | grep "$job_id" | grep -Eq '[[:space:]]r[[:space:]]'
    do
        printf "."
        sleep 1
    done
    printf "\n\n"

    local node_name="$(get_node_name "$job_id")"
    printf "Job is running on node $node_name \n\n"
}

wait_job_finish () {
    local job_id="$1"
    printf "waiting for job to finish"
    while qstat | grep -q "$job_id"
    do
        printf "."
        sleep 1
    done
    printf "\n\n"
}

check_for_job_submission () {
    local job_id="$1"
    if ! qstat | grep -q "$job_id" ; then
        echo "its there"
    else
        echo "not there"
    fi
}

get_node_name () {
    local job_id="$1"
    qstat | grep "$job_id" | sed -e 's|^.*[[:space:]]\([a-zA-Z0-9.]*@[^ ]*\).*$|\1|g'
}
# ~~~~~ RUN ~~~~~ #
printf "Submitting cluster job to get node hostname and IP\n\n"

job_name="get_node_hostnames"
job_id="$(submit_job "$job_name")" # Your job 832606 ("get_node_hostnames") has been submitted
job_id="$(echo "$job_id" | sed -e 's|.*[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]*\)[[:space:]].*|\1|g' )"
job_stdout_log="${job_name}.o${job_id}"

printf "Job ID:\t%s\nJob Name:\t%s\n\n" "$job_id" "$job_name"

wait_job_start "$job_id"
wait_job_finish "$job_id"

printf "\n\nReading log file ${job_stdout_log}\n\n"
[ -f "$job_stdout_log" ] && cat "$job_stdout_log"
printf "\n\nRemoving log file ${job_stdout_log}\n\n"
[ -f "$job_stdout_log" ] && rm -f "$job_stdout_log"
```

Sidenote: If you like Python, there is a slightly more robust equivalent [here](https://github.com/stevekm/pyqsub)

You'll probably have to do some little tweaks to both to adjust it for your PBS system, since this was written for SGE.

Comment: sidenote: you are probably better off just using a workflow manager such as [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html) for this; it submits to PBS automatically and automatically handles staging output files in and out

Answer (score 1):

You can just look for `" C "` with grep, but you could also just use `-o [hostname:]path` to stream to the final destination, as long as you have your ssh keys set up from the node for your POSIX account.

If you end up doing grep, you should be a good citizen and limit your check frequency to once or twice a minute, so as not to contribute to server spam, which can impact performance.